# "ob etwas" vs. "dass etwas"

Tags: difference

Wir suchen im Kontext von Mitarbeiterführung den Unterschied zwischen zwei Mustersätzen:

- Ich entscheide, **ob** etwas gemacht werden soll
- Ich entscheide, **dass** etwas gemacht werden soll.

Wo liegt der Unterschied?
Liegen wir richtig, dass *ob* den Ausgang offen lässt, also auch eine Verneinung möglich wäre und im Gegensatz, bei *dass* die Entscheidung schon gefällt ist (d.h. der positiv-Fall der zutreffende/erwartete ist)?

Bei Fragestellungen ist es eindeutiger:

- Ich glaube, **dass** es regnet. - *ziemlich sicher regnet es.*
- Ich frage mich, **ob** es regnet. - *ich habe keine Ahnung, es könnte auch trocken sein.*

Comment: Noch deutlicher wird es, wenn man folgende Aussagen vergleicht: Ich weiß nicht, ob/dass es regnet.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn jemand die Entscheidung trifft, **ob** ein Auto gekauft wird, dann sind zwei Dinge möglich:

> a) Das Auto wird gekauft.
> b) Das Auto wird nicht gekauft.

Ohne zusätzliche Informationen sind beide Möglichkeiten gleich wahrscheinlich. Die Entscheidung wird erst in der Zukunft gefällt.

Wenn jemand die Entscheidung trifft, **dass** ein Auto gekauft wird, dann heißt das unmissverständlich:

> Das Auto wird gekauft.

Eine andere Deutung dieser Aussage ist nicht möglich. Die Entscheidung ist bereits in der Vergangenheit gefallen (und wird spätestens mit dieser Aussage verkündet) und zwar zugunsten des Autokaufs.

Answer (score 1):

> Liegen wir richtig, dass *ob* den Ausgang offen lässt, also auch eine Verneinung möglich wäre und im Gegensatz, bei *dass* die Entscheidung schon gefällt ist (d.h. der positiv-Fall der zutreffende/erwartete ist?)

Ja, damit liegt ihr richtig. Genau so ist das.